# How to tune hyperparameters of microsoft LightGBM trees?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, boosting

I have a class imbalanced data & I want to tune the hyperparameters of the boosted tress using LightGBM.

***Questions***

1. Is there an equivalent of gridsearchcv or randomsearchcv for
   LightGBM?
2. If not what is the recommended approach to tune the
   parameters of LightGBM?

Please give solution preferably in python or even R.

Answer (score 3):

There is an official guide for tuning LightGBM. Please check out [this](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters-Tuning.html).

And for validation its same as any other scikit-learn model ...

```
     #LightGBM Regressor
     import lightgbm
     from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor
     lightgbm = LGBMRegressor( task= 'train',
          boosting_type= 'gbdt',
          objective= 'regression',
          metric= {'l2','auc'},
          num_leaves= 300,
          learning_rate= 0.32,
          feature_fraction= 0.9,
          bagging_fraction= .9,
          bagging_freq= 70,
          verbose= 100)

     scores = cross_val_score(lightgbm, X, y, cv=shuffle_split)
     print("Cross-validation scores:\n{}".format(scores))
     print("Average cross-validation score:{:.2f}".format(scores.mean()))
```

Hope it helped :)